# What constructive work can be done from spare 64 bit Ubuntu System

Tags: 13.04, software-recommendation

I have some Ubuntu x86_64 system lying around. I want to use them for good or maybe to show my students what all can be done using linux, distributed system and other software
Please guide me
Thanks

Comment: What's your question? What version of Ubuntu are you talking about? What constructive work are we talking about? What subject are you teaching the students, so you can show them relevant software.

Comment: This may be closed soon as **primarily opinion based** or **unclear what you are asking** you may want to ask this question on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What CAN'T be done with a spare Ubuntu system.

Learn/practice coding without the risk of tanking your main machine. And if you mess it up just reinstall.

[Set up a web server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) to experiment with web development

[Set up many kinds of servers](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-a-home-media-and-file-server-with-ubuntu): A file server is fairly simple to start with.

There are many more things that can be done with Ubuntu and it is an excellent platform for learning/teaching.